# How to prevent "Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree" when building Widget offscreen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to export a Widget as Image, that is wider than the actual Viewport.

I have found this method:

```dart
Future<Uint8List?> createImageFromWidget(Widget widget,
    {Size? logicalSize, Size? imageSize}) async {
  final repaintBoundary = RenderRepaintBoundary();

  logicalSize ??= ui.window.physicalSize / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
  imageSize ??= ui.window.physicalSize;

  assert(logicalSize.aspectRatio == imageSize.aspectRatio);

  final renderView = RenderView(
    window: ui.window,
    child: RenderPositionedBox(child: repaintBoundary),
    configuration: ViewConfiguration(
      size: logicalSize,
    ),
  );

  final pipelineOwner = PipelineOwner();
  final buildOwner = BuildOwner(focusManager: FocusManager());

  pipelineOwner.rootNode = renderView;
  renderView.prepareInitialFrame();

  final rootElement = RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(
    container: repaintBoundary,
    child: widget,
  ).attachToRenderTree(buildOwner);

  buildOwner.buildScope(rootElement);
  buildOwner.finalizeTree();

  pipelineOwner.flushLayout();
  pipelineOwner.flushCompositingBits();
  pipelineOwner.flushPaint();

  final image = await repaintBoundary.toImage(
      pixelRatio: imageSize.width / logicalSize.width);
  final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  if (byteData == null) return null;

  return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

From what I understand, this method builds the referenced Widget in a new Offscreen-Widgettree and sets the viewport size to the size of the Widget, that needs to get exported.

This method in and of itself works, but heres my problem:

I am referencing the `Widget` that needs to get exported by `GlobalKey`.

So it looks something like this:

```dart
Repaintboundary(
 key: myGlobalKey,
 child : WidgetIWantToExport()
);

void exportWidget(){
 final currentWidgetSize = myGlobalKey.currentContext!.size!;
 final keyWidget = myGlobalKey.currentWidget!;
 final pngBytes = await createImageFromWidget(
   keyWidget,
   logicalSize: Size(currentWidgetSize.width, currentWidgetSize.height),
   imageSize: Size(currentWidgetSize.width, currentWidgetSize.height),
 );
 //exporting bytes
}
```

So when I run this method, the `.attachToRenderTree()` throws an Error: `'_elements.contains(element)': is not true. ... Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.`

So I am assuming the problem is, that it tries to build a widget with the same GobalKey in the new RenderTree, which throws this error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by accessing the child of the Repaintboundary, that I am referencing by Key.

The code looks like this:

```dart
/// Creates an image from the given widget by first spinning up a element and render tree,
/// and then creating an image via a [RepaintBoundary].
///
/// The final image will be of size [exportViewportSize].
/// If no [exportViewportSize] is supplied, the image will be of size [logicalSize], which has a fallback value.
Future<Uint8List?> createImageFromWidget(Widget widget,
    {Size? logicalSize, Size? imageSize, Size? exportViewportSize}) async {
  final renderRepaintBoundary = RenderRepaintBoundary();

  final repaintBoundary = widget as RepaintBoundary; //casting the widget as RepaintBoundary

  final renderWidget = repaintBoundary.child!; //Accessing its child widget

  logicalSize ??= ui.window.physicalSize / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
  imageSize ??= ui.window.physicalSize;

  assert(logicalSize.aspectRatio == imageSize.aspectRatio);
  final renderView = RenderView(
    window: ui.window,
    child: RenderPositionedBox(child: renderRepaintBoundary),
    configuration: ViewConfiguration(
      size: exportViewportSize ?? logicalSize,
    ),
  );

  final pipelineOwner = PipelineOwner();
  final buildOwner = BuildOwner(focusManager: FocusManager());

  pipelineOwner.rootNode = renderView;
  renderView.prepareInitialFrame();
  final rootElement = RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(
    container: renderRepaintBoundary,
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: renderWidget,
    ),
  ).attachToRenderTree(buildOwner);

  buildOwner.buildScope(rootElement);
  buildOwner.finalizeTree();

  pipelineOwner.flushLayout();
  pipelineOwner.flushCompositingBits();
  pipelineOwner.flushPaint();

  final image = await renderRepaintBoundary.toImage(
      pixelRatio: imageSize.width / logicalSize.width);
  final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  if (byteData == null) return null;

  return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```